# Return a component instance by key (using Ninject Container)

Tags: dependency-injection, ioc-container, ninject

Is it possible to return a component instance by key using Ninject?

The equivalent to Castle Windsor is for ex.:

*container.Register(Component.For< ConcreteA >().Named("KeyForConcreteA"));*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Bind<ConcreteA>().ToSelf().Named("KeyForConcreteA")
var a = kernel.Get<ConcreteA>("KeyForConcreteA");
```